# I cannot delete a "Azure Domain-Services"-Ressource

Tags: active-directory, azure, deleting

we have the problem that we are not able to delete our "Azure AD Domain Services"-Domain.
Here you can see the current state:

[Error-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh8fu.png)

when we try to delete it, we get following message:

[Error-Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftg0K.png)

Now we have an "Orphaned"-Ressource, which is a bit annoying...
We cant create a support-ticket because we dont pay for this.
But for me its a Infrastructure-Problem from Azure itself.
Maybe someone can help me.
Thanks!
Leon

Comment: **We cant create a support ticket because we don't pay for this.** - Have you tried to open a support case? This might be something they will help you with.

Comment: Hi, as i said, we cant create because of our "support-plan". We dont want to pay for something azure have a problem with, you understand me? Thanks! Leon

Comment: You can still create a support ticket, just not a technical one. Create a billing ticket, which is free, stating you are paying for a service you no longer want, but can't get rid of

Comment: Thats the "workaround" i needed! Thanks for the tip.